# Spring MVC project not opening the view

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

iam new to spring framework am actually trying to create a spring mvc e-commerce project.i have updated everything and there has been no errors but strill i didnt get the landing page instead i get a 404!!!
here is my stacktrace...

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml,/WEB-INF/application-
context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<!--        <init-param> -->
<!--                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> -->
<!--                <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value> -->
<!--        </init-param> -->
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**POM.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pat</groupId>
    <artifactId>archangel</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>archangel Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
            <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.191</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>archangel</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.pat.controllers.*" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<bean 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

**Application-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.pat.*"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" 
  destroy-method="close">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test" />
     <property name="username" value="sa" />
     <property name="password" value="sa" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">  
              <list>  
                  <value>com.pat.*</value>  
              </list>  
    </property> 

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop 
key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"
 class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->

        <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->

</bean>

</beans>
```

**DroidController.java**

```
package com.pat.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.pat.model.User;
import com.pat.services.UserService;

@Controller
public class DroidController
{ 

    public DroidController() 
    {
        System.out.println("inside driod ctrlr.......");
    }

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    String message = "Welcome to Spring MVC!";

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView showMessage() 
    {
        System.out.println("in controller");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("homepage");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView Message() 
    {
        System.out.println("in controller 1");
        ModelAndView mv1 = new ModelAndView("login");
        return mv1;
    }


    @RequestMapping("/signup")
    public String gotoindex(@ModelAttribute("mand")User mand)
    {
        System.out.println("in controller 2");
        return "signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="saveuser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String gotoSignUp(@ModelAttribute("usrform")User usrform)
    {
        userService.insertRow(usrform);
        return "homepage";
    }

}
```

**Console**

```
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:archangel' did not find a matching property.
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.38
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 6 2016 20:51:55 UTC
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.38.0
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_102-b14
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Patrick Aditya\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         E:\NIIT SWs\apache-tomcat-8.0.38\apache-tomcat-8.0.38
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Patrick Aditya\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=E:\NIIT SWs\apache-tomcat-8.0.38\apache-tomcat-8.0.38
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Patrick Aditya\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=E:\NIIT SWs\apache-tomcat-8.0.38\apache-tomcat-8.0.38\endorsed
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/amd64;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;E:\NIIT SWs\eclipse;;.
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8007"]
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 3158 ms
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.38
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:58 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:58 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:58 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Apr 10 20:26:58 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:58 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Apr 10, 2017 8:26:59 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:00 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:01 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.pat.controllers.DroidController.showMessage()
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:01 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/signup],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.pat.controllers.DroidController.gotoindex(com.pat.model.User)
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:01 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/saveuser],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.pat.controllers.DroidController.gotoSignUp(com.pat.model.User)
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:01 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/login],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.pat.controllers.DroidController.Message()
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:01 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.4.Final
inside driod ctrlr.......
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:03 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.5.Final}
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:03 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:04 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:06 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7959 ms
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:06 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Apr 10 20:27:06 IST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 246 ms
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8007"]
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 11891 ms
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:07 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/archangel/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 10, 2017 8:27:26 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/archangel/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Comment: which url are you trying to hit? and can you post your file structure?

Comment: Am trying to open dat @RequestMapping("/") first @Moshe Arad

Comment: do you have a page name: homepage.jsp? where is it located? please share your file structure

Comment: my homepage.jsp is located in WEB-INF -> views -> homepage.jsp

Answer (score 0):

The `contextPath` is missing, if you are using tomcat, you need copy your war file to `webapp` folder, if your `war` file named `test`, you need to call `http://localhost:8080/test/` to fetch your homepage, but i strongly recommend you not to learn spring this way, try [Spring-Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) first, this is the new approach for spring, much simpler.

Comment: i think it is available in my eclipse

Answer (score 0):

use the below code for Application-context.xml path.

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
```